# How can I get the JComboBox popupmenu list as component object

Tags: java, swing, listener, jcombobox, popupmenu

In my swing application I have a dialog box with Combobox. In the I am applying the AffineTransformation . All the components are resizing but except JComponent popupmenu list is not scaling . I am trying with an event to get the Popupmenu object of the ComboBox.

```
 public static void displayComp(JComponent jComponent) {
    if (jComponent != null) {
        final Container awtContainer = (Container) jComponent;
        final Component[] components = awtContainer.getComponents();
        for (Component comp : components) {
            if (comp instanceof JComboBox) {

                JComboBox<JComponent> b = (JComboBox<JComponent>) comp;
                b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("e::" + e);
                        JMenuItem mi = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
                        JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu) mi.getParent();
                        System.out.println("popup:::" + popup);
                    }
                });
                System.out.print("JComboBox :::");
                System.out.println(comp.getPreferredSize() + "***Component**" + comp.getName());
            }

            if (comp instanceof JComponent) {
                displayComp((JComponent) comp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the popup component using following code

```
JComboBox combo = ...;
BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup) combo.getUI().getAccessibleChild(combo, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

JPopupMenu shown when you combobox is not child of the JCombobox. so AffineTransformation will not apply to it.